# How to make css3 steps animation using `position` property

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to make a steps animation using css3. but i am not able to get result.

requirements:

According to the array value `.digits` need to change it's top position. i have the `@keyframe` with the name of `move`. i am adding to the `.digits` on button click. but not working.

what is the correct way to do this?

her is my code :

```
<div class="container">
       <span class="roll">
         <span class="digits">
           <span class="digit">0</span>
           <span class="digit">1</span>
           <span class="digit">2</span>
           <span class="digit">3</span>
           <span class="digit">4</span>
           <span class="digit">5</span>
           <span class="digit">6</span>
           <span class="digit">7</span>
           <span class="digit">8</span>
           <span class="digit">9</span>
         </span>
       </span>
     </div>
     <button>change</button>
```

js part:

```
$(function(){

 var randomArray = ["3", "7", "9","4", "4", "2", "8", "0", "9"];
 var i = 0;

 $("button").on('click', function () {
    ++i;
    var steps = parseInt(randomArray[i])
    $('.digits').addClass('move').delay(100).queue(function (next) {
       $(this).css({
          '-webkit-animation' : 'scroll  1s steps('+i+')' //move according to the i steps (+/-)
       })
       next();
    });
 })

});
```

css part :

```
div.container {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 10px;
}

  .roll {
    display: inline-block;
    width : 20px;
    height : 20px;
    position : relative;
    overflow : hidden;
  }

   @keyframe scroll {
     0% 100% {top: 0};
    100% {top: -25px};
  }

  .digits {
    background :green;
    position : absolute;
    left :0;
    top:0;
    width : 100%;
  }

  .digits.move {
    -webkit-animation : scroll  1s steps(2);
  }



    .digit {
      color : white;
      display:block;
      line-height : 20px;
      text-align: center;
    }
```

[Live Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/kikCU0eImPItZf46pBAS?p=preview)

Comment: any reason why you aren't using jQuery's `.animate()`?

Comment: I agree.  for the editing purposes and transparency of property, css3 helps much. In case my approach not at all possible please show me using jQuery.

Comment: What is the end result you are looking for? You want the digits to change top value based on the number in the array?

Comment: yes. it like time count. I am trying like this `minute` number approach. http://codepen.io/kindofone/pen/DkhAz

Comment: Have you seen the error that plunker reports ? it should be keyframes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 .roll {
display: inline-block;
width : 20px;
height : 20px;
position : relative;
overflow : hidden;
 -webkit-animation: scroll 5s infinite; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
-webkit-animation-direction: alternate; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
animation: scroll 5s infinite;
animation-direction: alternate;
}

  @keyframes scroll {
0%   {left: 0px; top: 0;}
25%  {left: 200px; top: 25%;}
50%  {left: 200px; top: 50%;}
75%  {left: 0px; top: 75%;}
100% {left: 0px; top:100%;}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please consider at least adding some words on how you code snippet does answer the OP question.